# Paradox at $T=0$ in 1D Ising Model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, temperature, ising-model

How do we resolve the paradox in 1 D Ising model at $T=0$ where we have two ground states possible and accordingly the mean value of magnetization is $0$ but there is spontaneous symmetry breaking and the system chooses one state and the net magnetization is non zero. 
Is it related to the fact that when we perform a measurement on the system, the system collapses into one of the two ground states and thus we get non zero magnetisation?

But this argument also seems somewhat wrong because say all spins up and all spins down are the two eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. Then since both states have the same energy and are equally probable, any linear combination of these states will also be an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian. Then how can we say that a state which is an eigenstate (but a linear combination) will collapse into one of the eigenstates?

Comment: The usual way this is resolved is that small fluctuations in the ambient magnetic field break the symmetry. After all, you can never truly have zero field.

Comment: Where does this stray mag field come from? Is it due to electrons? And how does this extra field help to resolve the paradox?

Comment: Having any external field immediately causes one spin-aligned state to be preferred over another. Taking it to zero doesn't change this alignment. As to where it comes from, at some level we don't really care.

Comment: How can you say that this stray field will homogenously pointing along one direction so that one of the spin states (either all up or all down) will be preferred?

Comment: It doesn't have to be homogeneous, because the interaction between the spins is much stronger than the field. It just has to slightly shift the energies of the various ground states, because any of the partially-antialigned excited states are still way above the ground states in energy.

Comment: This will lead to some spins in the configuration to be pointing in one direction and some in other, then how will we have a Ferromagnet at T =0?

Comment: No it won't. Remember, the spins are interacting with each other. They want to be aligned. The addition of a tiny external field isn't going to change that. The only thing it will change is which _direction_ all of the spins align in, because even if a field is inhomogenous, it still (except in very contrived cases) imparts more energy to one ground state than the other.

Comment: By spontaneously breaking the symmetry, the system chooses one of the states (all up or all down), it does not attain any other state than these 2

Comment: I don't understand if none of the spins are going to flip, how does system gets biased to one of these states just due to presence of this field

Comment: There's no flipping going on. The ground state of the unbroken system is a superposition of "spins all aligned up" and "spins all aligned down." Adding a field makes either "spins all aligned up" or "spins all aligned down" less energetic, so the new de facto ground state of the system is the less energetic of the two states.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73684/discussion-between-cool-5275-and-probably-someone).

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to solve this "paradox".

The first one is to say, like it was suggested by [probably_someone](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/139781/probably-someone) in the comments, that a realistic system will never be perfectly isolated from magnetic fields. An infinitesimal external magnetic field will be enough for one of the two ground states to be favored, thus selecting one of the two ground states in the limit $T\to 0$.

The second resolution is more formal. Apparently, if the Hamiltonian $\mathcal H(\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_N) = \mathcal H (\{\sigma_i\})$ is invariant under reversal of all the spins $\sigma_i \to -\sigma_i$, then also the canonical probability of the state $\{\sigma_i\}$

$$P[\mathcal H\{\sigma_i\}]=\frac{e^{-\beta \mathcal H(\{\sigma_i\})}}{Z} \tag{1}$$

will be invariant under the same transformation. This means that  the magnetization

$$m \equiv\langle \sigma_i \rangle = \sum_{\{\sigma_i\}} \sigma_i P[\mathcal H (\{\sigma_i\})]$$

must always be $0$, since $m$ and $-m$ occur with equal probability.

For a finite volume system, the correctness of this argument is irrefutable: *there are no (true) phase transitions at finite volume*. A finite-volume Ising model will only *apparently* select a defined magnetization as $T\to0$, but if you wait long enough (an exponentially long time with the system size $N$), the magnetization will eventually reverse, over and over.

However, as $V \to \infty$, $(1)$ becomes only formal, since the partition function diverges. In this case, this argument is incorrect, and it can be shown that while

$$\lim_{V\to \infty} \lim_{h \to 0^{\pm}} m = 0$$

you have

$$ \lim_{h \to 0^{\pm}} \lim_{V\to \infty} m = \pm 1$$

This is what we call *spontaneous symmetry breaking*: even in the absence of an external field (which would *explicitly* break the symmetry), a single ground state is selected over the two possible ground states.